# Boost thread and signal handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, signals, boost-thread

I want to know how I can trap signals using boost thread. I know how to do this using pthreads but can't find a solution in boost.

I want to trap error exceptions signals like - sigsegv etc in the thread so that the whole program does not crash if one thread has this error.

I can always do this using the underlying pthread library directly but wanted to know if there was a portable way of doing this in `boost::thread`.

Comment: I like to use Boost Asio's `signal_set` for this (some [examples of use can be found in my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20signal_set))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process cannot [reliably](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG35-C.+Do+not+return+from+a+computational+exception+signal+handler) resume execution after receiving a `SEGV` signal. If your program must remain running under such circumstances, fence off the offending code into a separate process and communicate over IPC. That said, boost [provides](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/signals.html) a nicely integrated `signal_set` in the [boost-asio](/questions/tagged/boost-asio) library for handling signals.

```
void handler(
    const boost::system::error_code& error,
    int signal_number
    )
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // A signal occurred.
  }
}

...

// Construct a signal set registered for process termination.
boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT, SIGTERM);

// Start an asynchronous wait for one of the signals to occur.
signals.async_wait(handler);
```

Comment: Ok i will look into boost::asio. But can you clarify -  "Your process cannot reliably resume execution after receiving a SEGV signal". The thread that caused SEGV cannot be resumed but other threads can continue. I will just exit the offending thread and let the rest continue. Am i wrong in doing this??

Comment: @Rohit yes that is an incorrect assumption. It may work **sometime** but fail other times, which is why you cannot reliably continue execution. That is the definition of *undefined behavior*.